# Python - Preventing closing a file after printing its content

Tags: python, input, file-read

I want to read a file with python, print its contents first, and then do my operations on its data.

Here is my code:

```
with open("myFile.txt", 'rw') as inputFile:
    print(inputFile.read())
    for i,j in enumerate(pdbFile):
        do whatever
        count the lines 
print("Number of lines", numberOflines)
```

The output in this case is `numberOfLines = 0`.

However, if I comment the command        `print(pdbFile.read())`, it gives me the correct number of lines. So apparently the file is being closed after reading the file.

How to force python to keep the file open until I finish my calculations?

Comment: No, the file is not closed. You just can't read a file more than once without rewinding to the start.

Comment: Add `pdbFile.seek(0)` or read once into a variable, then print the variable and loop over the `.splitlines(True)` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you `read()` the file, you reached the end of it, and though your file is still open, there is no line left to iterate on.

So, either:

- Don't `read` it before your `for` loop, or;
- Go back to the start of the file after reading it with `seek(0)`, or;
- Close it and open it again.